# Scrolling and display problem (bug?) in LibreOffice 3.6 and above

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, libreoffice, versions, zooming

This problem started with a new version of LibreOffice, 3.6.2.2. (the one with the new green splash screen instead of the old white one) and continued up to the latest 4.x versions.

My documents are not displayed properly when I scroll up or down.

**The problem appears only above a certain zoom level** and is the same in odt or doc.

Example. Have pasted a text here

[image]

After scrolling down:

[image]

and down:

[image]

and then up:

[image]

Clicking on the text restores it but it always goes back to the beginning which is the only part that is visible in this way - and larger documents are almost unusable!

The document can be taken under control **if the zoom is equal or lower than 180%**. It may vary depending on display and resolution, but it seems to me that **the problem disappears as soon as the zoom goes down so that the page is largely within the margins of the maximized window**.

[image]

On my display the comfortable zoom level (the one that I would prefer to use, and cannot) would be 230%  (e. g. with 11 Arial).

---

- This also affects other parts of the office suite (Calc, Impress).
- I never had display problems with this laptop before, and previous versions of Libreoffice worked ok.
- I have tested with a live usb and the same LibreOffice version and the problem appears in the same manner.
- **This happened initially in Lubuntu 12.10, and then in Xubuntu 12.10 too, and in all versions of LibreOffice above 3.5.**
- I am able to use msoffice 2007 under Wine with no problem. To avoid the present issue, I use LibreOffice 3.5.

Comment: @cipricus Just apply system update (selectively) in the Live environment. As long as your RAM can hold the changed compared to the state of the Live CD, this is possible (thanks to SquashFS).

Comment: my present solution: downgraded to 3.5

Comment: i have largely re-edited the question and flagged to re-open

Comment: @cipricus - still reads like a bug - have you reported this both on launchpad - and preferably on the libreoffice bug tracking system/mailing list?

Comment: @fossfreedom - hope [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65603) stands as a bug report

Comment: as i have no solution to this, i have cross-posted [this on ask.libreoffice site](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/18743/scrolling-and-display-problem-bug-in-libreoffice/), and i also have found a similar question [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/10032/librewriter-screen-display-text-gets-messed-up/) with a comment saying that openoffice is not affected by this: but that may be because openoffice is behind libreoffice. at the present(june 2013) LO is v.4.0.1, while OO is 3.4.

Comment: @cipricus - yep - I would follow the recommendation and use Bibisect to find the issue.  It may take a couple of days but I'm sure you'll find the commit(s) that caused the issue.

Comment: @fossfreedom - sadly i should first start reading, and that is not first on my list. also, very unlikely me using virtualbox or linux 64...