# How to get back my proper display driver settings after (wrongly) installing AMD Catalyst Control Center?

Tags: drivers, display, radeon

After having [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/238098/47206), and following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/238119/47206), I have installed AMD Catalyst Control Center (fglrx-amdcccle) and after reboot my display was all wrong, stuck to 1280x1024.

I have un-installed it but could not repair it.

Before all this happened,  running `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga` I got:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
    nee ATI M24 1P [Radeon Mobility X600] [1002:3150]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company nx8220 [103c:0934]
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

But now i get:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI M24 1P [Radeon Mobility X600] [1002:3150]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company nx8220 [103c:0934]
    Kernel modules: radeon, radeonfb
```

For some reason a `radeonfb`  appears beside `radeon` as  kernel driver in use.

How to go back to the previous state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the  [gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239164/47206), I looked at this question: [Google Chrome not rendering webpages correctly](https://askubuntu.com/q/161450/88802) which initially was supposed to solve [my other problem related to Openoffice](https://askubuntu.com/q/238098/47206).
There, I looked at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/197425/47206), and took the first two steps from there,

> sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon

which after reboot have restored my LXRandr ability of setting my display.

[image]

Now

> ~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga

gives:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI M24 1P [Radeon Mobility X600] [1002:3150]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company nx8220 [103c:0934]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

like before the installation of AMD Catalyst Control Center.

(Also, in this way, my Libreoffice problem mentioned above, which had disappeared when this one here emerged, is back. I welcome the kind readers of this post to consider reading my other question and provide an answer that would not produce this problem here again.)

Answer (score 3):

Just uninstall the Catalyst Control Centre. You don't need it in your situation, as it relies on running the `fglrx` driver. If it pulled in some dependencies and you want them to be gone as well:

- [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/q/187888/88802) (see the `apt-get autoremove` part)

Your GPU is supported by the open source driver `radeon`, which has proper [XRandR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) support so the Ubuntu integrated tool can do all configuration and you have proper [KMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_setting) support. This is the recommended driver for your hardware, if I'm correct.

The `radeonfb` kernel module is just [part of the regular Linux kernel image](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=radeonfb.ko&mode=&suite=quantal&arch=any) and provides very basic [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) rendering and communication to the card. I bet if you just remove the CCC and reboot it'll be gone. I suspect the CCC `modprobe`'d it, but then errored out and didn't bother `rmmod`'ing it. If it doesn't fix it, try to find what causes it to load (e.g. `/etc/modules`) or [blacklisting it](https://askubuntu.com/a/110343/88802).

For your original issue, you could try to actually completely switch to `fglrx` (if supported) and see if it helps out like reported in this question:

- [Google Chrome not rendering webpages correctly](https://askubuntu.com/q/161450/88802)

However, it seems that was not working out for you, so I'm just posting this for other ones bumping into this question later.

Comment: your answer guided me to a solution that i posted as answer. but now the other libreoffice-related issue is back