# Can I use an older version of LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, downgrade, versions

Quantal has 3.6. I feel that the new version is heavier - at least for my specs. (Beside having [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/238098/47206) problem).

How could I install an older version of LibreOffice?

Comment: I can see the sense in requiring an older version. LibreOffice Writer 6.0 and 7.0 in combination with Ubuntu 20.04 O/S introduces a bug in endnotes you can waste days researching and trying to fix unsuccessfully. One step forward two steps back. Whatever happened to the old saying If it ain't broke don't fix it? On Ubuntu 18 and older version of Libre Writer, everything worked fine. Introducing new versions before testing thoroughly makes people think twice about accepting updates at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't done this, but you should be able to

1. Uninstall the current version using Ubuntu Software center or `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core`
2. Then go to either:

   - [this page](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?nodetect) for the latest stable versions of the two current branches;
   - [this list](http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/) of older LibreOffice versions;
   - or [this page](http://archive.services.openoffice.org/pub/openoffice-archive/stable/) for even older versions of OpenOffice;
   - and download the .deb package for your environment.
3. Then install using `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`

---

Source for the full list of older LibreOffice versions is [this](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/18742/where-to-download-the-deb-35-version-as-well-as/?answer=18751#post-id-18751) ask.libreoffice answer.

Comment: It worths noting that from example from this URL http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/3.3.4.1/deb/x86_64/ the main installation package will have a name like this one `LibO_3.3.4_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz` (It is hard to miss that file between so much files present)

Answer (score 4):

Old (and magically also most new) versions at:

- http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/

Be careful to download from /deb folder.

After download:

1. extract archive.
2. go in the /DEBS folder.
3. "open in terminal" or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
4. `cd ~/home/monos/Downloads/LibreOffice_4.1.4.2_Linux_x86-64_deb`
5. `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

well done! libreoffice is installed!