# How to downgrade from LibreOffice 4.0 to 3.6?

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, downgrade

[How to "properly" downgrade LibreOffice versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108704/how-to-properly-downgrade-libreoffice-versions) deals with a downgrade from 3.5 to 3.4.*. Is there any way to nicely downgrade LibreOffice 4.0 to 3.6? The latter is not in the package lists.

**Background**: It is because of [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60592) which is about the incompatibility of [an extension](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/template-changer) which should really be core functionality. Essentially, 4.0 just does not deal with templates in an intelligent way. You cannot fully apply a template to an existing document.

**Update**: based on `apt-cache showpkg libreoffice` (found on [How to Downgrade a Package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get?rq=1)) one can confirm that only LibreOffice 4.* is in the repositories.

Comment: You could [add this LO 3.6 repo](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-3-6) and then proceed to ppa-purge the 4.0 repo. Haven't tried this out myself but it should work in principle.

Comment: In the technical details it states that this is for quantal and precise. Will it work for raring as well or will it leave a mess behind?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I am still on 12.04

Comment: @don.joey didn't work for me on raring - `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-3-6/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found` => apt-cache only offers 4.0.2.

Comment: Do you still want this?

Comment: @Braiam No the extension for which I wanted to do this has been merged. I am not sure which of these answers works.

Comment: So, should we close this? The reasons why you wanted to do this doesn't apply anymore, no?

Comment: @Braiam I don't think so. It can be relevant for someone else who wants to downgrade for another reason. If we close it, will it be deleted?

Comment: nah, make them ask their own question, and yes, it could get deleted, but that would require 3 10kers votes. I don't see any answers that could work here for the same proposes.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then remove ppa for LibreOffice4
Add ppa for LibreOffice3.6

```
sudo apt-get update
```

via synaptic reinstall packages which make problems for me it was libexttextcat

Install LibreOffice via synaptic.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. I downgraded from LibreOffice 4.4 to 4.2. However, I do not think Synaptic is necessary. I did all in terminal.  I installed with: sudo apt-get install libreoffice and this worked fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to downgrade but not as "nicely" as I would like.

1. Install Synaptic `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
2. Uninstall libreoffice `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice`
3. Add the Libreoffice 3.6 ppa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-3-6`
4. Refresh the repositories list `sudo apt-get update`
5. Install LO 3.6 `sudo apt-get install libreoffice=1:3.6.6-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1` . I never done this but there is information on how to install specific version [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/92021/27968).
6. Open Synaptic, search for Libreoffice, select the package and from the package menu select **Lock version**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem of downgrade too (from 4.1 to 4.0.4 ).
Found this solution in a libroffice page & it's working fine!

> If you have no menus on a Debian/Ubuntu-based system or trouble with
>   the install, you likely didn’t uninstall the distro version of
>   LibreOffice completely. You will need to make sure all the binary
>   packages listed here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice
>   are uninstalled. On Ubuntu releases, executing:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*  
sudo apt-get purge openoffice.org-dtd-officedocument1.0 python-uno python3-uno uno-libs3 ure
```

*Source:* https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.1#Most_Annoying_Bugs