# How to downgrade to a specific PPA version of LibreOffice?

Tags: apt, ppa, libreoffice, downgrade

Since 2012 I have been using [LibreOffice provided by this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa). But yesterday, I made an upgrade which contains a [bug that messes with all my Sheets](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74558).

While I wait for a fix, I want to downgrade from the current version 4.2.0.4 to the previous version 4.2.0.3.

I've found several articles to downgrade from the PPA to "default" version 3.6 but none that downgrade to a specific PPA version:

- [How to "properly" downgrade LibreOffice versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108704/how-to-properly-downgrade-libreoffice-versions)
- [Remove all packages installed from a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363653/installed-libreoffice-4-with-ppa-how-do-i-remove-it-and-go-back-to-libreoffice)

**Is it possible to do a version downgrade using standard apt commands?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, just do `sudo apt-get install libreoffice=version`. It will downgrade, remove and install to whatever version you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to manually download the necessary `.deb` files from the PPA, then using `sudo dpkg --force-downgrade -i your_libo_package.deb`. Be careful with this option and be sure to have read `man dpkg` before using it.

For a more detailed account of this downgrade procedure see:

- [How can I downgrade packages without removing their dependants?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414345/how-can-i-downgrade-packages-without-removing-their-dependants)