# Downgrading libreoffice from repository

Tags: ppa, libreoffice, repository

I am trying to downgrade from `libreoffice 4.3.0~rc1` to the most recent `stable 4.2.0`.

This is on account of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1333073) .

I have seen this question about [How to downgrade to a specific ppa version of libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418487/how-to-downgrade-to-a-specific-ppa-version-of-libreoffice) which suggests

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice=version
```

but I can't figure out how to specify the version.

`libreoffice=4-2` or `libreoffice=4.2` or `libreoffice=4.2.0` all give me variations on

```
E: Version '4-2' for 'libreoffice was not found
```

I have also tried

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo add-apt repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

but that also gives me the new, unworking 4.3 version.

Any suggestions? I suppose I could install from the .deb files, but I'd rather use a repository version if possible.

Note that:

```
apt-cache policy libreoffice
libreoffice:
  Installed: 1:4.3.0~rc1-0ubuntu1~precise0.2
  Candidate: 1:4.3.0~rc1-0ubuntu1~precise0.2
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.3.0~rc1-0ubuntu1~precise0.2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages 

but "sudo apt-get install libreoffice=1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1.0"
returns
"E: Version '1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1.0' for 'libreoffice' was not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
apt-cache policy libreoffice
```

You should get output that looks something like this:

```
libreoffice:
  Installed: 1:4.2.4-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:4.2.4-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.2.4-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

The one with `***` is your currently installed one (or maybe it's the candidate version.. I'm not positive now that I think of it)

To install specifically, say, the second one (in my case) you would type

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice=1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2
```

Comment: I tried this and selected the second one on the list: "sudo apt-get install libreoffice=1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1.0" : "E: Version '1:3.5.7-0ubuntu 6.1.0' for libreoffice was not found"; also, I don't see any version 4.2 showing up in the apt-cach policy, any idea why?

Comment: Can you edit your original post with the results of apt-cache policy libreoffice?

Comment: modified, as requested

Comment: So while I'm not sure where you'd get it, 1.4.2 is not in any of the ppas/sources that are available to you

Comment: I am not trying to install 1.4.2, I am actually trying to install the latest stable version. 4.2.5.2. I went ahead and installed from the .deb file, which seems to work fine for now.

Comment: oops, you're right - I was reading 1:4.2.4 as 1.4.2.4 rather than 4.2.4