# lubuntu 16.04, 64 bit: Libreoffice 5 crashes desktop session

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, mate

I installed Lubuntu 16.04 on an Acer Extensa 2511, 64-bit
(then I installed ubuntu-mate-desktop and ubuntu-mate-core).
With both lubuntu and MATE, Libreoffice WRITER crashes often, shutting the desktop session down and bringing me back to the login window.
I tried to reinstall libreoffice; to remove libreoffice and MATE and to install MATE again,; to reinstall jre. None of these worked.
I dont't think the problem is MATE rather than Lubuntu/lxde, this happened with lubuntu as well before installing MATE the fist time.
Libreoffice version is 5.1.

Comment: Did you try to disable OpenGL (if it it enabled)? Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> View -> Graphics Output: Disable "Use Hardware acceleration" and "Use OpenGL for all rendering"

Comment: Thank you. I just did, but Libreoffice crashed again (still shutting the desktop session down and bringing me to the login screen). I also increased the allocated memory (Options -> Tools -> Memory)  from 20Mb  to 300Mb for Libreoffice and from 5.2Mb to 20Mb for each Object. After another crash I tried to check the box "use Libreoffice dialog windows" in Tools->General .  But then it crashed again.  Remark that I make these tests with very small files: a Writer file and an Impress file. Crashes seem to happen when I use dialog windows, i.e. resizing or changing color of an Impress element.

Comment: i add that dialog windows are drawn quite slowly. After a crash, the recovery window appears (slowly), but choosing "recovery" results in an immediate crash.

Comment: Aww - quite bad situation! I fear the best thing you can do is filing a bug on launchpad, adding as much log file info / terminal output and hardware config as possible (see [this bug report, for example](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1537566)). I'm very sorry about this!

Comment: Finally I decided to reinstall the whole system - So installed just MATE, this time. Libreoffice comes with the MATE installation, and it seems to work. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

So far how I could solve it was by downgrading libreoffice to a previous version. For that I followed this answer: [How to "properly" downgrade LibreOffice versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108704/how-to-properly-downgrade-libreoffice-versions) suggested by Cipricus.

I installed version 5.1.1 and it seems to work better.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I decided to reinstall the whole system - So installed just MATE, this time. Libreoffice comes with the MATE installation, and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Libreoffice and installed Openoffice instead, it works fine for me. I'll keep using Openoffice until an update for Libreoffice that fixes the problem will be released.

Comment: The OP is asking how to fix it with libreoffice, not install OpenOffice.